# Concatenating numbers in javascripts and php

Tags: javascript, php

I translate some code from javascript to php, my problem is with numbers, because in javascript "+" is used in both situation, addition and concatenating.
ex:

```
1+1+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"" + 2
```

in javascript result is 22372

How can I make this in php? I try with preg_replace

```
1+1 --> 2
2+"2" --> "22" // as string
""+2 --> "2"
```

problem is here:

```
(1+1+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1)+""+2
```

I need to solve () then concatenating with "" and 2

Comment: Just do `1 + 1 . "2"  ."4" . 3 - 5 - 1 . "" . 2`

Comment: JavaScript wants to be smart and it ends confusing users. `+` does addition when both operands are numbers but it turns into concatenation if one or both of the operands are strings, no matter if they contains numbers. PHP uses different operators for the two operations: `+` always means addition (it converts its operands to numbers by finding their longest numeric prefix), `.` always means concatenation (it converts it operands to strings, no matter their types and/or values).

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is done with "." rather than "+" in php. You can still concatenate values of different types, e.g.

```
$apple_count = 25;
$my_string = "I want " . $apple_count . " apples.";
```

Comment: this is NOT what I want.

Comment: @vb6rocod It _is_ what you want though.  If you replace all the `+` with `.` (except for the first one, which you want to be addition) then you get `echo 1+1 . "2" . "4" . 3 - 5 -1 . "" . 2;` which produces your desired result.

Comment: I don't know how is expresion, it's from a javascript and is changed... can be now 1+"22" or next time to be 2-3 if you understand me. I need a general solution (if any) So I don't know value for $apple_count, or if I have any concatenation or is a simple math. expresion and I don't need concatenation. Hope to understand my dilema... when is addition (+) and when is concatenation (.)

Comment: @vb6rocod You want to evaluate a general javascript expression? I guess the simplest, most correct solution is simply to use a javascript interpreter. For example you can do it with node.js using exec in php: `exec("echo 'console.log($expression)' | node")`

Comment: @vb6rocod Or you can take a look at projects such as php-js which allows you to run javascript inside php: https://www.php-js.com/documentation/introduction

Answer (score 0):

I work on a solution

```
echo $a." = 22372"."\n";
function concat_num($a) {
 while (preg_match("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",$a) || preg_match("/^(?!\-)\s*(\d+)\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",$a)) { // "10" + 2 or 2 + "10"
 while (preg_match("/(\d+)\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",$a)) {    //1 + 2 --> 3
  $a=preg_replace_callback(
    "/(\d+)\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",
    function ($m) {
      return floor($m[1]+$m[2]);
    },
    $a
    );
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/\"\"\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",$a)) {
  $a=preg_replace("/\"\"\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",'"'."\$1".'"',$a);  // ""+11   ---> "11"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/(\d+)\s*\+\s*\"\"/",$a)) {
  $a=preg_replace("/(\d+)\s*\+\s*\"\"/",'"'."\$1".'"',$a);  // 11+""   ---> "11"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*\"\"/",$a)) {
  $a=preg_replace("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*\"\"/",'"'."\$1".'"',$a); // "11"+"" --> "11"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/\"\"\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",$a)) {
  $a=preg_replace("/\"\"\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",'"'."\$1".'"',$a);  // ""+"22" -->"22"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",$a)) {
  $a=preg_replace("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",'"'."\$1\$2".'"',$a); // "11"+"22" --> "1122"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",$a)) {
  $a=preg_replace("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\+\s*(\d+)/",'"'."\$1\$2".'"',$a); // "11"+22 -->> "1122"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/^(?!\-)\s*(\d+)\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",$a,$m)) {
 $a=preg_replace("/^(?!\-)\s*(\d+)\s*\+\s*\"(\d+)\"/",'"'."\$1\$2".'"',$a); // 11+"22" --->> "1122"
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/\"(\d+)\"\s*\-\s*(\d+)/",$a)) {  // "10" - 8 --> 2
  $a=preg_replace_callback(
    "/\"(\d+)\"\s*\-\s*(\d+)/",
    function ($m) {
      return floor($m[1]-$m[2]);
    },
    $a
  );
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 while (preg_match("/(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)/",$a)) {    //5 - 2 --> 3
  $a=preg_replace_callback(
    "/(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)/",
    function ($m) {
      return floor($m[1]-$m[2]);
    },
    $a
    );
 }
 echo $a."\n";
 }
 return $a;
}
echo $b=concat_num($a)."\n";
$code="\$d=".$b.";";
eval ($code);
echo $d."\n";
```

And result

```
1+1+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"" + 2 = 22372
2+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"" + 2
2+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"2"
2+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"2"
2+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"2"
2+ "2" +"4"+3 - 5 -1+"2"
2+ "24"+3 - 5 -1+"2"
2+ "243" - 5 -1+"2"
"2243" - 5 -1+"2"
2238 -1+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
2237+"2"
"22372"
"22372"
"22372"
"22372"
22372
```

This seems to work but the best solution is to evaluate string from beginning to end.

```
1+1 --> 2 (num)
2+"2" --> "22" (string)
"22"+"4" --> "224" (string)
"224"+3 --> "2243" (string)
2243-5 --> 2238 (num)
2238-1 --> 2237 (num)
2237+"" --> "2237" (string)
"2237"+"2" --> "22372" (string)
```